# When not to use AJAX client-side routing?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, client-side

Using client-side routing (with Angular's `$routeProvider` for example), it is possible to load a whole web app at once and not interact with the server anymore.

However this might imply a long load time when visitors first open the web app assuming it has a lot of views.

What are the best practices in terms of client-side routing vs. initial load time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the default behaviour of angular is to have the whole app front loaded. But it depends what your app does and how big it is. If it's a small app you could do that. If your app is  huge (unlikely given all the app will do is just show some static data) then it's not really a good idea to load everything up front. For a smaller app it would be OK, especially if you minify everything. But for larger apps, what if you have 10MB of scripts and resources? You're putting a lot of strain on your server and eating your customers bandwidth. Fr large apps you could dynamically load scripts as routes change, we do something similar [to this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) in a pretty huge angular app.

The best practice would be to only get the files that are required to generate the content you want to show to the user on that specific route, which goes against what you want to do. Regarding "not interact with the server anymore", well if your app relies on a server to get some data or do some authentication, you can't really stop interacting with the server.

Comment: Thanks. I will apply "1 route = 1 set of files delivered at once"